# Look and feel of final site design

Tags: discussion, top-7, design

I found a question on logo design.
However I didn't find any on the rest of the look and feel of the final site.

I created a question to contain suggestions of what the theme for the site should be.
Suggestions for the button styles, colour theme and things go here.
Quoting from [The 7 Essential Meta Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta) "We have designers on staff to come up with site designs but, if an idea stemming from the community stands out as exceptional, we are happy to use it."
So we can suggest if we want.

Basically, what do we want our new rpg stack exchange site to look like?

Answer (score 6):

I like the graph paper. Slap a couple of dungeon rooms in one corner and a relationship map in another corner and you've got something. It'd be kind of cool if the dungeon map was also the relationship map... does that make sense? I'll see if I can sketch out something to show what I mean.

Comment: Not quite sure I know what you mean by relationship map, could you explain what one is? Thanks.

Comment: Relationship maps are charts showing how NPCs relate to one another. Super-handy for highly social games. If you ever played first edition Vampire: the Masquerade, the factions in the Chicago sourcebook all had relationship maps. I think that's the first example in RPGS. There's another typical relationship map here: http://www.darkshire.net/~jhkim/rpg/shadowsinthefog/relationsmap.html

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd start with the suggestion of keeping a handwritten look and feel to the buttons and tags.
The handwritten theme says rpg to me, particularly if it's in a fairly natural colour scheme.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to offer my day job experience as a graphic designer for anything that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more a fan of the darker color schemes.  They seem easier to read to me.  Plus, there's the whole playing off the "underground" or "in space" feel.  I would also suggest a dragon (or some other stereotypical, symbolic creature) in the logo.

Comment: A dragon isn't generic enough.

I think personally that dice are probably the most generic visual hook.