# "The Site Will Be Launching Very Soon"! How awesome is THAT!?

Tags: discussion, site-status

So I was curiously following-up on the [“How is the site going” entry in area51. Comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/556/how-is-the-site-going-entry-in-area51-comments) question, and I checked out our [Area 51 entry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games), to discover that - where it once counted down the days to the end of our private beta - it now says:

> This site is nearing the end of its beta and will be launching very soon.

... and we no longer have any "worrying" stats; worst we have are an "okay" number of questions and an "okay" number of views per day.

**How awesome is that?!**

Likewise, what does all this mean? (in the past, I've been a shining example of "users who don't really understand what's going on" and I'm sure there are others)

Are we soon to have our own site design, like [Seasoned Advice](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/)? If so, activity should flock towards the questions which will be relevant:

- [Site logo design?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108/site-logo-design)
- [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/553/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)
- [Look and feel of final site design](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/look-and-feel-of-final-site-design)

Comment: "It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument." :P Great news though, thanks for the update.

Comment: It's official, we are out of beta!

Comment: What!? Link please! [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games)  still says public beta to me :'(

Comment: It says public beta, but if you read on it says "This site has finished its beta and will be launching very soon."

Answer (score 7):

Yes, once we graduate, and all the metrics indicate that we will, we'll get a design and everything.  Although there may be a backlog; there's one person doing it for all the sites and they'll be queued in order of "excellence". So don't expect a new design to happen immediately (note that everyone on area51, if past 90 days, is still listed as "passed beta and launching soon" but don't have designs yet, and there's like 9 ahead of us.)

Robert Cartiano wrote:

> Folks have been asking when their site
>   is going to graduate. Here is how that
>   is decided... Looking at Area 51
>   (progress tab), any site past 90 days
>   goes into a pool of sites to graduate.
>   Jin is able to design about 1 to 1-1/2
>   sites per week so we have to come up
>   with an order to launch those sites...
>   Based on this blog post When Will My
>   Site Graduate?, the sites with enough
>   2000 and 3000-rep users go first. The
>   order after that is determined by the
>   Area 51 statistics: The most
>   Excellent, Okay, and Worrying, in that
>   order.

I'm sure they'll take our thoughts on meta into account so do feel free and put in design/tagline ideas (do not expect them to be held to them though - my expectation is that professional graphic design will win over design-by-committee when necessary).

Comment: ♫ Awesooooome ♪

Comment: Most people aren't going to be able to see that chat conversation; the room is mods only

Comment: Then they need to get them some more rep!  OK, OK, cut and pasted the relevant bit.

Answer (score 3):

One other thing to note is that most users' privileges will be reduced, as Beta site privileges are given out at much lower rep levels than full sites.

Comment: Is there a concordance that can be looked at that gives an idea of the comparative rates?

Comment: @Jadasc: There's a chart in the [When will my site graduate](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) blog post.